# randomized data trasnformation in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, transform, torchvision, data-augmentation

I want to rotate all the images in my `Dataset` with a random degree between `[0,180]`. If I compose a transformation function and pass my images to this function in the `__getitem__` function of my `Dataset` class. Does this mean:

1. every single image is randomly rotated?
2. images in each batch get rotated with an identical degree but this degree randomly changes across batches (calls)?

I would appreciate it if you could clarify this for me.

Answer (score 1):

In mapped datasets, `__getitem__` is used to select a single element from the dataset.

The way random transformations work in PyTorch/Torchvision is they apply a unique random transformation each time the transform is called. This means:

1. Every single image in your dataset is indeed randomly rotated **but not by the same amount**.
2. Additionally images in a batch get different transformations. In other words, elements in the batch won't share the same transformation parameters.

---

Here is a minimal example with a dummy dataset:

```
class D(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = n
        self.transforms = T.Lambda(lambda x: x*randint(0,10))
    
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.transforms(index)
        return x
```

Here you can see the random transformer *inter* and *intra* batches:

```
>>> dl = DataLoader(D(10), batch_size=2)

>>> for i, x  in enumerate(dl):
...     print(f'batch {i}: elements {2*i} and {2*i+1} = {x.tolist()}')
batch 0: elements 0 and 1 = [0, 2]
batch 1: elements 2 and 3 = [14, 27]
batch 2: elements 4 and 5 = [32, 40]
batch 3: elements 6 and 7 = [60, 0]
batch 4: elements 8 and 9 = [80, 27]
```

Comment: thank you very much. About two points that you are making, I see them as the same thing meaning: if every datapoint gets a random transformation (assuming we use only one transformation) then each batches transformation will be different so 1 and 2 will be equal. Am I correct or I am missing something?

Comment: Indeed, all elements have different transformations applied, *a fortiori* batches have different transformations as well.